# Pickling data in python

Tags: python, binary, pickle

I have been staring at this code for a day and a half now and google is not helping. It looks fine to me but it keeps throwing out errors.

The program runs through a quiz and collects a score at the end as shown here:

```
print("That was the last question!")
print("Your final score is", score)
name = input('What is the players name? ')
highsc = highscore(score, name)
```

I Know that score works but when i enter the players name it then tries to run my highscore definition:

```
def highscore(score, name):

    entry = (score, name)

    hs_data = open('tops.dat', 'rb')
    highsc = pickle.load(hs_data)
    hs_data.close()

    hs_data = open('tops.dat', 'ab')
    highsc.append(entry)
    highsc.sort(reverse=True)
    highsc = highsc[:5]
    pickle.dump(highsc, hs_data)
    hs_data.close()

    return highsc
```

But the i get the same error each time which is:-

```
File "C:\Users\Desktop\py3e_source\py3e_source\trivia_challenge.py",     line 55, in highscore
    highsc = pickle.load(hs_data)
File "C:\Python31\lib\pickle.py", line 1365, in load
    encoding=encoding, errors=errors).load()
EOFError
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening an empty file, `pickle` is reaching the end before it finds anything to **unpickle**. You can fix this by catching the `EOFError` and setting a default value when caught.

Something like this should work:

```
with open('tops.dat', 'rb') as hs_data:
    try:
        highsc = pickle.load(hs_data)
    except EOFError:
        highsc = []
```

Comment: Or you delete the file when the EOFError occurs and create a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, i used this 
`if not os.path.exists('tops.dat'):
        hs_data = []
        make_file = open('tops.dat', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(hs_data, make_file)
        make_file.close     
    else:
        None`

Because if the file didn't exsist already then it would cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

The error says EOFError, which means you have reached the end of the file and pickle was not in a normal state. Is the file filled before using that function?

Also, opening the file in append mode to write the new data doesn't seem like a good idea. load reads the entire file, not discarding characters after the first object, but once you have  added a new highscore, you have two highscore objects in the file, which also leads to an error.

Comment: The file isn't filled before calling this function, this is something i was considering might be wrong with it but unsure as how to fix. Should i define a list first?

Comment: Yes, just use an empty list instead of unpickling an empty file.

Comment: I'm told the programme is supposed to store the data in a binary file using pickle for a challenge.

Comment: You can store the data using pickle, but do not unpickle empty data. Use an empty list if you can't unpickle the file (as Wessie suggests).

Comment: I have solved my initial problem with the errors but i have a new problem because when i try to append my file it doesn't save the information it seems, should i post a new question or try and ask the question in here?